# One's Complement in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I have a value:

```
int source = 123;
```

I want the *one's complement* of the same `int`. How? 
Is there some *inbuilt function* for the same in c#?

Comment: `int source = 123; int result = ~source;`

Answer (score 1):

~ is the complement

i = ~123    -- for example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [~ operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-complement-operator) (**bitwise not**):

```
  int source = 123;
  int result = ~source; // 1's complement of the source

  // Let's have a look at the source and result
  string testReport = string.Join(
     Environment.NewLine,
     Convert.ToString(source, 2).PadLeft(32, '0'),
     Convert.ToString(result, 2).PadLeft(32, '0'));

  Console.Write(testReport);
```

Outcome:

```
00000000000000000000000001111011
11111111111111111111111110000100
```

Comment: Cannot pad. it changes the complete value. doesn't it?

Comment: @Sayan Sen: `.PadLeft(32, '0')` doesn't change anything: I turn `source` into `string` (`source` has not been chnaged) and then pad this string in order to format out the demo output.